# How to set the rowlimit in content query webpart by code?

Tags: 2010, development, 2013

I need a content query web part that returns me the last 10 modified or added documents into any document library on that specific website.

How can I add the rowlimit by code?

```
ContentByQueryWebPart cqwp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
                                cqwp.ContentTypeBeginsWithId = "0x0101008E49C3D400044AB3A2F1DD14073E74F6001D06D12572244BE3A11AAEE3ED60F576";
                                cqwp.WebUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;
                                cqwp.Title = "Last Updated Documents";                                
                                string query = @"<Where> "+
                                                    ""+
                                                "</Where>"+
                                                "<OrderBy> "+
                                                    "<FieldRef Name='Modified'  Ascending='FALSE'/> "+
                                                "</OrderBy>";
                                cqwp.QueryOverride = query;
                                cqwp.ListsOverride =  "<Lists ServerTemplate='101'></Lists>";
                                cqwp.WebsOverride = "<Webs Recursive='False' />";
                                cqwp.ViewFieldsOverride = @"<ViewFields> " +
                                                                "<FieldRef Name='Type' Nullable='True' Type='Text'/> " +
                                                                "<FieldRef Name='Name' Nullable='True' Type='Text'/> " +
                                                                "<FieldRef Name='ContentType' Nullable='True' Type='Text'/> " +
                                                                "<FieldRef Name='Modified' Nullable='True' Type='DateTime'/> " +
                                                                "<FieldRef Name='Modified By' Nullable='True' Type='Text'/> " + 
                                                            "</ViewFields>";                               

                                mgrPageManager.AddWebPart(cqwp, "Footer", 0);
                                mgrPageManager.SaveChanges(cqwp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the RowLimit property of your SPQuery object because the  is in the schema definition of a view not on the `<Query>`.

Comment: there is no such SPQuery object on a content query webpart, there is only queryoverrides which is a string

Comment: what about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.itemlimit.aspx